# What is the meaning of the square brackets in “.module("modulename", […])” of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I just saw an [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm) of routing in AngularJS. I would like to know the relation ship between dependency `'ngRoute'` and module `mainApp`, in synatx `var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);`.

Previously I've seen examples with empty square brackets in module declaration.

Below is the whole context of code:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

  mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
     function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
           when('/addStudent', {
              templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
              controller: 'AddStudentController'
           }).
           when('/viewStudents', {
              templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
              controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
           }).
           otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/addStudent'
           });
     }]);
```

Comment: `[]` it is defining an array in this case...

Comment: `[]` defines an array, in this case, an array of dependencies

Comment: `setters(name, something); getters(name)`

Comment: This is well [documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) on the AngularJS site. Please put in some effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[...]` defines an array

**In the angular case.**

`mainApp` is a main module( main array)  and `ngRoute` is a sub module(like  array of object).

The sample is

```
var ngRoute=[];//{}

var mainApp=[ngRoute];// now the `mainApp` includes the `ngRoute`
```

Answer (score 3):

In angular, when defining a `module`(creating it), you pass it the names of other `module`s it depends on as an array (in square brackets).

In your example, the `mainApp`-`module` depends on the `ngRoute`-`module`, making the components of `ngRoute`(directives, services, factories, values...) available for dependency injection for the components in `mainApp`. To define a `module` that does not depend on any other modules, you pass an empty array (`[]`) [See the angular documentation for some more info on modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#dependencies)